# DeadLock process Which one locks first?

Tags: java, concurrency

Consider the following:

```
public class Deadlock {
static class Friend{
    private final String name;

    public Friend (String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }


    public synchronized void bow(Friend bower){
        System.out.format("\n%S: %S has bowed to me!" , this.name, bower.getName());
        bower.bowBack(this);
    }
    public synchronized void bowBack(Friend bower) {
        System.out.format("\n%S: %S has bowed back to me!", this.name, bower.getName());
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Friend alf = new Friend("Alf");
    final Friend arian = new Friend("Arian");

    // Thread 1
             new Thread(new Runnable()  {
        public void run(){ alf.bow(arian);}}).start();

    //Thread 2
    new Thread(new Runnable()  {
        public void run(){ arian.bow(alf);}}).start();  
}
```

}

The out put is

ALF: ARIAN has bowed to me!
ARIAN: ALF has bowed to me!

LOCK situation.....

When Thread 1 runs, it requires a lock on the object Friend. Immediately after that Thread 2 requires lock on the second object. Now the method ***bow***  is lock by thread 1 and thus prints "ALF: ARIAN has bowed to me!". How comes Thread 2 enters ***bow*** and neither can enter *** bowBack *** ??

Regards B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bear in mind that `synchronized` methods will always synchronise on `this`.

There are two objects and therefore two locks. `alf.bow()` acquires `alf`s lock and `arian.bow()` acquires `arian`s. But then `bowback()` tries to acquire the other one, which is when the deadlock happens.

If you want to synchronise on a shared lock object, you should do something like this:

```
class Friend {
   private static final Object lock = new Object();

   public void bow(...) {
     synchronized( lock ) {
        ...
     }
   }

   public void bowback(...) {
     synchronized( lock ) {
        ...
     }
   }

}
```

Since `lock` is in a static field, it means all instances of `Friend` use the same lock object, therefore there's no chance of a deadlock.

You can also synchronise on the class object `synchronized( Friend.class ) {...}`, but synchronising on externally visible objects usually isn't a good idea as there's no guarantee that some other part of the code doesn't steal the lock.

Answer (score 3):

Synchronization is done using any object; threads can enter simultaneally in synchronized blocks if they are synchronized with different objects.

The `synchronized` keyword in an instance method means that the block is synchronized **by that instance**. Since you are calling the `bow` method of two different objects, there is no control that both execute such function at the same time.

synchronize by the class object (or use an static final object created to that end).

Answer (score 1):

**-** You have used `2 objects`, and **both the Threads here are using 2 different Monitor locks.**

**-** As both the threads are having lock on `2 different object`, its quite obvious that the locking of thread 1 on the object 1 has no effect on the thread 2 taking the lock of object 2.

**-** You have used `synchronized` keyword which require an **object lock here**, and you are providing both the threads with their own object locks, so thread 2 enter the bow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to lock on a common object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Object lock = new Object();
    final Friend alf = new Friend("Alf", lock);
    final Friend arian = new Friend("Arian", lock);
    ...  
}


public  void bow(Friend bower){
    synchronize(lock){
        System.out.format("\n%S: %S has bowed to me!" , this.name, bower.getName());
        bower.bowBack(this);
    }
}
public void bowBack(Friend bower) {
    synchronize(lock){
        System.out.format("\n%S: %S has bowed back to me!", this.name, bower.getName());
    }
}
```